# Initialize and InitializeAsync fires once vs OnNavigatingTo that fired when navigating back too Prism 7.2

Tags: prism

I have moved my project to prism 7.2

I have quite a few "OnNavigatingTo" and replaced accordingly with InitializeAsync or Initialize

If I remember correctly "OnNavigatingTo" was firing every time you navigated to a page whether to or back. If I was navigating back to a page it would fire whilst Initialize doesn't.

This whether correct or wrong is causing me issues with some of my pages where I was passing back parameters when navigating back .

Is this the intended behavior?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnNavigatingTo was only ever supposed to fire once. It's intent was to initialize. There ended up being cases where it fired more than once. Anything you require done once should be placed in `IInitialize.Initialize` anything that should be fired each time you navigate or requires some logic like Navigated Back to... should be in `INavigat[ed|ion]Aware.OnNavigatedTo`.

It was this confusion that led so many Prism users to request that the support be dropped and a new API be introduced that made the intent clearer.

Comment: S . Well i guess i have to clean my "misuse" the problem and correct if I am wrong that if you are navigating back and you have updated some data and you want that new updated data reflected on the page you are going back to you will see the values changing  after the page has been drawn. So I need to update the values before the page is drawn again when I return back. hope clear if not .thanks for your clarification